# Periodic function with period $T$; show that there exists a point in the interval with $f(x) = f(x + T /2).$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$: $R\rightarrow R$ be a continuous periodic function with period $T > 0$.
>   Show: There is an $x \in R$ such that $$f(x) = f(x + T /2).$$

Trivial case: If $f(x)$ is constant, this statement is always true, but this cannot happen as $T>0$, and for a constant function $T=0$, so we are not dealing with a constant function.

This really feels like an intermediate value theorem question, but I am very used to working with concrete functions and wouldn't immediately know how to apply this to an arbitrary function. What do I know about this function?

1. $f(x)$ is continuous, useful.
2. $f(x)=f(x+T)$ for every single $x$ in the domain.
   My intuition tells me it would be useful to consider the values $x=0$ and $x=T$, but to which function would I apply this?

Comment: You don't need to exclude $T=0$, because $f(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yeah I know, it might as well be $T \geq 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g(x)=f(x)-f(x+T/2)$, $g(0)=f(0)-f(T/2)$, $g(T/2)=f(T/2)-f(T)=f(T/2)-f(0)$ apply intermediate value to $[0,T/2]$ since $g(0)$ and $g(T/2)$ have opposite signs.

Comment: I see, this argument makes sense, thank you.

Comment: I can argue that for some value $c$, we have that $g(c)=0$ and Bob's your uncle, thanks!

Comment: A similar approach is to argue that if $f(x) \neq f(x+T/2)$, then we must have $f(x) > f(x+T/2)$ for all $x$, or $f(x) < f(x+T/2)$ for all $x$. Then $f(x+T) > f(x+T/2) > f(x) = f(x+T)$, contradiction.